# Can't boot into Kali linux, system hang

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot

My Asus ROG laptop dualboot Kali/Win10 wont boot after dist-upgrade. Im getting what appears to be an error:

[image: Screenshot of boot]

The system  hangs. Ive tried reinstalling several times with no luck. This is a completely fresh install with the latest ISO from their website.
I was able to boot just fine a few days ago but when I ran dist-upgrade it no longer boots, even after reinstalls. I am able to boot from a live USB, however and I can boot into recovery mode.

Comment: This is an installation issue and it matches with the fact that you get it repeatedly after installing (probably exactly the same faulty way), yet working from another disk.  It seems to be a driver issue related to your graphics adapter.  I would guess you installed something after the default installation, right?

Comment: No, I fresh install and when the installer says to reboot, it wont boot back up. I've tried the 2016.2 build as well as the weekly build, same problem.

Comment: I remember once trying to run lspci | grep VGAwhile in recovery and the command line froze. I could still type characters but nothing would happen.

Comment: You should take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/388269/585715

Comment: So the problem is that i cant install anything because i cant even ctrl alt f1. I can load a live USB, wouldnt that run off the same graphics driver as the defauly operating system?

Comment: An error I get when installing is about missing firmware files: iwlwifi-8000c-24.ucode. According to the internet it is a non-error message and should be ignored. My wifi card works fine when installing (ive been able to connect to a network as required by the installer).

Comment: You're right since that notice is followed by an attempt at loading the 23, then 22, then 21, and so on until it hits a version match.  That is **not** what I was looking at.  The fact that the install drive works doesn't give you any clue on whether you chose or installed the necessary drivers on your system.

Comment: So I pointed you to the simplest first solution to try ( http://askubuntu.com/a/388269/585715 ) before sending you on a really long and annoying mission to troubleshoot these darn NVidia driver issues which are all over the place.  Everyone that buys those products should complain to NVidia and perhaps some day they'll make a small effort in providing better solutions to their Linux users.

Comment: I've figured out how to install this aall in recovery mode but kali doesnt have a nvidia-current. Im trying this instead http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux

Comment: Now it boots past the previous point but i am getting a "white screen of death". "Oh no! Something has gone wrong"

Comment: Look at your logs and `dmesg` output.

Comment: How to check logs?

Comment: When you get that `Oh no` message, try going in a shell with `CTRL-ALT-F1`.

Comment: Yeah I can do that, now I'm getting an error where, when booting, it says "Started user management for UID 133" and hangs

Comment: OK, if that's what you see then it means that the main console is on tty1, you can move to `CTRL-ALT-F2` for another tty and look at the logs and `dmesg` from there.

Comment: I can sort of use ALT-F1 but it's buggy. The screen switches from boot log window thing to the tty window quickly. It makes it impossible for me to enter my password as I can't see which characters are not being entered. I can still boot into recovery mode and when I press ctrl + d from there it immediately happens after the wifi card initializes

Comment: Like I said, try going on ALT-F2.

Comment: I meant ALT+F2,

Comment: Then keep going by trying the 3rd one: ALT-F3 :)

Comment: I have tried all of them, same problem on all. I can get  'journalctl -xb' and 'dmesg' from recovery mode

Comment: This is the dmesg result: http://pastebin.com/mNhUu8Mh
This is journalctl -xb result : http://pastebin.com/xXv8dVjq

Comment: The only thing I see is a Plymouth error

Comment: If you don't see any result with `ls -l /bin/plymouth`, then you'll have to reinstall that package with something like `apt-get install plymouth plymouth-drm`.

Comment: after installing plymouth, it boots up to "Started Hostname services" then hangs again. Exact same situation as before. Will look for differences in journalctl

Comment: Heres the results: http://pastebin.com/3XpWi8vk

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong in there.  And you don't see any relevant log updates: `ls -ltr /var/log`?

Comment: What should I be looking for? Any of the listed files?

Comment: I booted into normal mode now, let it sit for 10 minutes and the switching has stopped. I can access a normal tty but the main one is still not doing anything. However, the cursor is flashing and the latest entries are about wlan0: link not ready.

Comment: Ah here is something, under xorg.0.log I found an error: (EE) No devices detected (EE) no screens found)

Comment: So I think I know how to solve the devices part but no clue about the screens part. Will add BusID and boardname to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: That again points to a driver issue.

Comment: Yes but I have tried reinstalling drivers and installing different drivers. I installed http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/112992/en-us

Comment: I understand and this is why I'd never **ever** use a NVidia adapter on a Linux installation.

Comment: Well I'm running it on a laptop that has an nvidia card as well as integrated Intel

Comment: After manually changing the xorg.conf I've got "Started LSB: thin initscript"

Comment: Actually what seems to be hapening is after starting the user manager it stops it. "Started user manager for UID 133" "Stopped user manager for UID 133". then it remounts the main partition and then loads more stuff

Comment: This is interesting http://pastebin.com/pg8gkb80

Comment: Is there a way I can connect the intel device to the display screen and stuff and then use nvidia for Cuda (i.e oclhashcat)?

Comment: That's the way it's designed.  The Intel adapter is a proxy to the NVidia adapter.

Comment: Ah, well installing bumblebee and setting up the nvidia as a discrete driver seems to have fixed it. Gdm3 is now loading on boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing Bumblebee drivers after uninstalling all other drivers (nouveau)

Comment: Good for you! :)